# How can I get this to return the last lines in a SQLite db controlled by how many players played the game?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Im trying to get this code to return the scores and names of each player in an SQLite database depending on the amount of players in the game so if there's 4 return the last 4 rows and if there's 2 return the last 2.

```
package dev.owen.a22006760;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GameComplete extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHandler dbHandler;
    GameMaker get = new GameMaker();
    int PlayerCount = GameMaker.GetPlayers();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_complete);

        dbHandler = new DBHandler(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getReadableDatabase();


        // Define your table and column names from DBHandler
        String tableName = DBHandler.tableName;
        String columnName = DBHandler.DBName;
        String columnScore = DBHandler.DBTotal;

        // Query the last 4 rows
        String query = "SELECT " + DBHandler.DBId + ", " + columnName + ", " + columnScore + " FROM " + tableName +
                " ORDER BY " + DBHandler.DBId + " DESC LIMIT " + PlayerCount ;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        // Process the results
        StringBuilder resultString = new StringBuilder();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHandler.DBId));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName));
            String score = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnScore));

            resultString.append("ID: ").append(id).append(", Name: ").append(name)
                    .append(", Score: ").append(score).append("\n");
        }

        // Close the cursor and database
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // Use the resultString as needed
        String finalResult = resultString.toString();

        TextView Results = findViewById(R.id.ResultsLab);
        Results.setText(finalResult);
    }


}
```

This is my current code for doing so, but the cursor keeps pointing to -1 and I don't know how to fix it, this is the layout of my code for fetching the amount.

This is the layout of the Database
[image: Database]

I want the code to output the total scores and name of the last lets say 4 players in the database. so..

4   Player 4. 21
5   Player 1. 15
6   Player 2. 20
7   Player 3. 19
8   Player 1. 11

(Without the indexes on the side)

I'm trying to put this into a string which can then be put in a TextView on Android Studio. Without the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query looks incorrect.
After the word `LIMIT` there should be a number.
And if you don't need a limit, remove the word `LIMIT`.